# How do I get a param from a URL and save it to var else use default

Tags: javascript, url, parameters

I just tried this JS code to get a parameter from the URL of a website. ?color=#HEXCODE and if there is no param of ?color I want it to apply the default colour.

What am I missing below?

```
    var color = url.searchParams.get("color");

    if (color) {
        var color = color;
    } else {
        var color = ("#5e46e8");
    }
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. What makes you think you are missing something?

Comment: @Quentin because it only shows the default colour when I have added a custom colour to the URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const queryString = window.location.search;
console.log(queryString);
//URL?product=bag&color=blue&newuser&size=m

const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
const color = urlParams.get('color')
console.log(color);
// blue
if (!color) {
    urlParams.set('color', "red");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning the `color` variable with a new value doesn't mean it will update the **url color** param.

You need to `set` the `color` param to the URL.

```
var color = url.searchParams.get("color");

if (!color) {
    url.searchParams.set('color', "#5e46e8");
}
```

Comment: I got the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: url is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13     I added ?color=#2d50e9 to end the of the URL